# How do you update Installed Product information with WIX DTF?

Tags: wix, windows-installer, dtf

Using DTF i can get the installed product fine using the following code.

```
        var product = (from p in ProductInstallation.AllProducts
                       where p.Publisher == CompanyName && p.ProductName == ProductName
                       select p).FirstOrDefault();
```

But the properties i want to update don't have a setter. Like the Version. Everything else in DTF seems to be against an MSI not an installed product

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't have a setter because that wouldn't make sense  If I have FOO.MSI 1.0 and install it, it gets registered with MSI.  Why would should I then be able to tell MSI that it's really 1.1?  I'd have to get FOO.MSI 1.1 and performa an upgrade in order to be able to do that.

Comment: The problem is the files are patched with a separate service but the windows installer detects the change and runs a repair. I need a way to tell it what its been updated to

Comment: While you should only service (patch) and MSI with an MSP, I happen to know from (renegade) experience that as long as you version the EXE/DLL files higher  MSI won't trigger a repair (resilency) and if you manually invoke a repair your higher version will remain.  If you do however delete the DLL and do a repair you'll get the old version back.

Comment: right, what would happen if you replaced it with the same version? would it do a repair? BTW the original install is done using InstallShield.

Comment: Provided InstallShield wasn't set to "always overwrite" it would be preserved.